Is there anything wrong in this for loop? CarMake returns data but CarModel does not
from .models import CarMake, CarModel

def initiate():
    print("Populate not implemented. Add data manually")
    car_make_data = [
        {"name":"NISSAN", "description":"Great cars. Japanese technology"},
        {"name":"Mercedes", "description":"Great cars. German technology"},
        {"name":"Audi", "description":"Great cars. German technology"},
        {"name":"Kia", "description":"Great cars. Korean technology"},
        {"name":"Toyota", "description":"Great cars. Japanese technology"},
    ]

    car_make_instances = []
    for data in car_make_data:
            car_make_instances.append(CarMake.objects.create(name=data['name'], description=data['description']))


    # Create CarModel instances with the corresponding CarMake instances
    car_model_data = [
      {"name":"Pathfinder", "type":"SUV", "year": 2023, "car_make":car_make_instances[0]},
      {"name":"Qashqai", "type":"SUV", "year": 2023, "car_make":car_make_instances[0]},
      {"name":"XTRAIL", "type":"SUV", "year": 2023, "car_make":car_make_instances[0]},
      {"name":"A-Class", "type":"SUV", "year": 2023, "car_make":car_make_instances[1]},
      {"name":"C-Class", "type":"SUV", "year": 2023, "car_make":car_make_instances[1]},
      {"name":"E-Class", "type":"SUV", "year": 2023, "car_make":car_make_instances[1]},
      {"name":"A4", "type":"SUV", "year": 2023, "car_make":car_make_instances[2]},
      {"name":"A5", "type":"SUV", "year": 2023, "car_make":car_make_instances[2]},
      {"name":"A6", "type":"SUV", "year": 2023, "car_make":car_make_instances[2]},
      {"name":"Sorrento", "type":"SUV", "year": 2023, "car_make":car_make_instances[3]},
      {"name":"Carnival", "type":"SUV", "year": 2023, "car_make":car_make_instances[3]},
      {"name":"Cerato", "type":"Sedan", "year": 2023, "car_make":car_make_instances[3]},
      {"name":"Corolla", "type":"Sedan", "year": 2023, "car_make":car_make_instances[4]},
      {"name":"Camry", "type":"Sedan", "year": 2023, "car_make":car_make_instances[4]},
      {"name":"Kluger", "type":"SUV", "year": 2023, "car_make":car_make_instances[4]},
    ]

    for data in car_model_data:
            CarModel.objects.create(name=data['name'], car_make=data['car_make'], car_type=data['type'], year=data['year'])

Opened up my python shell to test my models. First tested my CarMake model for output
for car_make in CarMake.objects.all():
    print(car_make.name, car_make.description, car_make.country)

which returns data appropriately. Then tried on my CarModel model
for car_model in CarModel.objects.all():
    print(car_model.name, car_model.type, car_model.year)

which returns empty.
Also launched my app on the browser and returns an empty list.

in the .models module, is there a difference in the constructors (objects.create) or get/set accessors? Are the str() or repr() methods defined for any of the objects (or are they just inherited from a standard type)?
